# How to get Subquery nearest distance?

Tags: mysql

I have a query to get the distance after calculated based on latitude and longtitude store in database table.

Each user had their own latitude and longtitude, I'm trying to get the centre name that are the nearest to the location of the user. But my query will having error when there are 2 location that is quite near to the user, how can i get the nearest centre name that can return in the subquery?

Below are my PHP Query:

```
SELECT
t1.id, t2.name AS na_name, t3.name AS centre_name, t1.login, t1.login_lat, t1.login_long,
        (SELECT centre_name  
        from centre_location where
        (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( t1.login_lat - centre_lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( t1.login_lat * pi()/180) * COS(centre_lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( t1.login_long - centre_long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) <= 0.18
) AS LOGIN_LOCATION,  t1.login_location_accuracy,
        t1.logout,  t1.logout_lat, t1.logout_long, (SELECT centre_name  
        from centre_location where
        (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( t1.logout_lat - centre_lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( t1.logout_lat * pi()/180) * COS(centre_lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( t1.logout_long - centre_long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) <= 0.18 
) AS LOGOUT_LOCATION, t1.logout_location_accuracy,  t1.attendance_device_type , t1.remark
FROM attendance t1 
left join user t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id
left join centre t3 on t1.centre_id = t3.id
where t1.id = 10130
```

I did try with ORDER BY and LIMIT 1, but the result is still not correct. Please refer below:

```
SELECT
t1.id, t2.name AS na_name, t3.name AS centre_name, t1.login, t1.login_lat, t1.login_long,
        (SELECT centre_name  
        from centre_location where
        (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( t1.login_lat - centre_lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( t1.login_lat * pi()/180) * COS(centre_lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( t1.login_long - centre_long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) <= 0.18
ORDER BY (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( t1.login_lat - centre_lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( t1.login_lat * pi()/180) * COS(centre_lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( t1.login_long - centre_long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) <= 0.18 DESC LIMIT 1
) AS LOGIN_LOCATION,  t1.login_location_accuracy,
        t1.logout,  t1.logout_lat, t1.logout_long, (SELECT centre_name  
        from centre_location where
        (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( t1.logout_lat - centre_lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( t1.logout_lat * pi()/180) * COS(centre_lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( t1.logout_long - centre_long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) <= 0.18 
ORDER BY (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( t1.logout_lat - centre_lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( t1.logout_lat * pi()/180) * COS(centre_lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( t1.logout_long - centre_long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) <= 0.18 DESC LIMIT 1
) AS LOGOUT_LOCATION, t1.logout_location_accuracy,  t1.attendance_device_type , t1.remark
FROM attendance t1 
left join user t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id
left join centre t3 on t1.centre_id = t3.id
where t1.id = 10130
```

The centre_name should have only return 1 value so that I can display/export to the result that I want, but there was sometime the centre_name been return more than 1 row, how can I get the nearest value that return ?

Comment: How about `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`? BTW: What is your server version?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I did try to order by and limit 1, but the result return is very random
Sometime show Location A sometime show Location B

Comment: Please post your attempt with ORDER BY. And once gain: What is the server version?

Comment: Server version?

Comment: Get the server version with `SELECT VERSION()`. I'm asking this because from 5.6 on you can use [ST_Distance()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance), from 5.7 on you can use [ST_Distance_Sphere()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere) and from 8.0 on you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number).

Comment: my version is 5.7.19

Comment: where show i add this ST_Distance_Sphere() ?

Comment: `where ST_Distance_Sphere(POINT(t1.login_long, t1.login_lat), POINT(centre_long, centre_lat)) <= 180` (180 meters).

Comment: getting incorrect statement st_distance_sphere

Comment: @Dharman because i'm using this query in my PHP code

Comment: @Dharman just to hope any PHP expert who did having this problem before could help

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i had added the order by and limit 1

Comment: @Dharman ok. but do you have any idea to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your ORDER BY clause is as following:

```
ORDER BY (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( t1.login_lat - centre_lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( t1.login_lat * pi()/180) * COS(centre_lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( t1.login_long - centre_long) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) <= 0.18 DESC LIMIT 1
```

To write it short:

```
ORDER BY (<distance calculation>) <= 0.18 DESC LIMIT 1
```

While it should be

```
ORDER BY (<distance calculation>) LIMIT 1
```

You should remove `<= 0.18`. You probably also want `ASC` (shortest distance first) instead of `DESC` (longest distance first).

Comment: However - It's out of scope for this question - But you should try to get `ST_Distance_Sphere()` to work.